# Changin NavigationController with MVVMCross (xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I'm developing my frist APP for IOS by using Xamarin and MVVMCross. This APP will be a login View, and then a menu view with link to another views. I use XIB files to design the controls and ShowViewModel navigation system control for the flow of screens. I read I need to do a custom presenter.

I hide the navigation menu on the login view but I want to show it in the second view but the navigation menu shows the "back" button, and I don't want that the user goes back to the login view and I want to customize the navigation menu. Can you help me with this?

Thank you

I start the viewmodel with application.cs which heritages from  MvxApplication

```
this.RegisterAppStart<LoginViewModel> ();
```

APPdelegate.cs

```
[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate
{
    // class-level declarations

    public override UIWindow Window
    {
        get;
        set;
    }             

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {    
        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        var setup = new Setup(this, Window);
        setup.Initialize();

        var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        startup.Start();    

        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible(); 

        return true;
    } 
}
```

loginview

```
public partial class LoginView : BaseView<LoginViewModel>{
    public LoginView() : base("LoginView", null)
    {
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();             
    }

    partial void DoLogin(UIButton sender) {
        this.ViewModel.DoLogin();
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true; 
    }     
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code? It's a bit difficult to figure out what the problem might be without it.

Comment: @DavidKristianLaundav I posted some code. As you can guess, there're many files. I posted Login VIew. DoLogin() calls the menuview with       this.ShowViewModel<TabViewModel> ();

Comment: Thanks. Could you possible also post the second view that you navigate to from your LoginView? That seems to be where the root of your issue is.

Comment: @DavidKristianLaundav it is exactly the same than loginview but change the name by TabView and NavigationControler.NavigationBarHidden = false.

Comment: It sounds like your LoginView screen doesn't need to have a navigation controller at all, just your second Controller, that or you just need to make sure your NavigationController.RootViewController is set to that Second Controller which will cause it to not have the back button.